# concat two *chars w/o string functions?

Tags: c, pointers, concatenation

I'm trying to figure out how I can concatenate two *chars together without using string copy and string concatenate.

I have this so far:

```
char *concat(char *pt1, char *pt2)
{
    char* c;
    c = malloc(strlen(a) + strlen(b));
    return c;
}
```

If I was using the string functions I could just do:

```
  strcpy(str3, str1);
  strcat(str3, str2);
```

any hints?

Comment: Add 1 for terminator. `c = malloc(strlen(pt1) + strlen(pt2) + 1);`

Comment: Check the return value from `malloc()`. Then copy from each string until 0-terminators reached.

Comment: Thank you, forgot about the terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by `Weather Vane`, add 1 for terminator`'\0'`. Use this in your function :-

```
char *concat(char *str1, char *str2)
{
  char* str3; 
  int i=0; 
  str3 = malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1);
  if (str3 == NULL) 
    return NULL;
  while(*str1){
    str3[i++]=*str1++;
  }
  while(*str2){
    str3[i++]=*str2++;
  }
  str3[i]='\0';
  return str3;
}
```

Comment: of course this is what strcpy / strcat etc would do, but would do it more efficiently. I presume that this is a homework assignment

Comment: Not a homework question. I knew I had to use a loop but nothing I tried work because of that terminating character. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You loop and copy characters.  If you want to optimize for this particular operation then you hold on to the end pointer of the destination string after copying the first string to it and use that to start copying the next string rather than looping to find the end again or adding the length to the start pointer of the destination.